# Can text be scraped from Grammarly to google spreadsheet using IMPORTXML function?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, screen-scraping

I am trying to get texts from the Grammarly application imported into a Google spreadsheet using the IMPORTXML function. To do so, I follow the required syntax IMPORTXML(URL, xpath_query), but it keeps showing an error that the "imported content is empty".
However, the same steps work fine to import data from other websites, and I am confused what might be the matter with Grammarly. Is it because it does allow data scraping at all, maybe?
Thanks for your help.  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPaDa.png) [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMTtf.png) [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGPQS.png)

Answer (score 0):

not possible because this is behind the login gate. google sheets cant read such data

Comment: I see. Thank you.